# How i can make number from the list is less than 18, then the number is not printed?

Tags: python

```
#Code
x = [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6]
   for y in x:
        if y < 18:
            y = x.copy()
            print (y)
```

In answer python:[17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6], [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6], [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6], [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6], [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the values, if the value is valid (`>=18`) keep it in an other list, at the end print them

```
x = [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6]
valid_values = []
for y in x:
    if y >= 18:
        valid_values.append(y)
print(valid_values)  # [18, 21]
```

With list-comprehension

```
valid_values = [y for y in x if y >= 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building a new list and printing the result:

```
x = [17, 15, 18, 21, 5, 6]
print(*[v for v in x if v >= 18])
```

**Output:**

```
18 21
```